# socketio inter server communication with redis and haproxy

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, haproxy

I'm working on a project which uses SocketIO and should be Horizontally scalable. Im using

- A Load Balancer using HAProxy
- Multiple Node Servers (2-4)
- Database server(Redis and MongoDB)

I'm able to redirect my incoming Socket connections to Node servers using roundrobin method. Socket connection is stable and if I use socket.emit() I'm receiving the data. I'm also able to emit to the Other socket connection connected to the same Node server.

I'm facing issue in the following scenario:

User A connected to Node server 1 and User B connected to Node Server 2

My intention is to store the Socket data in redis

If User A wants to send some data to User B, how can I tell the Node server 2 to emit the data to User B from Node server 1

Please let me know how can I achieve this (with ref if possible).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is a match for the case Pub/Sub of `Redis`.

If you haven't already, you should try [Pub/Sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [socket.io Redis adapter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis). It should be exactly what you need.

[clients()](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis#redisadapterclientsroomsarray-fnfunction) method in particular looks promising. Keep in mind, that socket.io creates a unique room for each client.